# Restrict threads to certain groups in JMeter

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I have the following scenario:

1. Run thread group a once at setup
2. Run a separate thread group b once at setup
3. Repeatedly loop requests in thread group c.
4. make all those threads that participated in groups b and c run thread group d
5. Make the thread that participated in thread group a run thread group e

How do I do this? It's number 1 and 5 that I'm not sure about, and how to make sure threads from a don't participate in c.

Comment: I'm not quite following what you're intend to do at stage 4. Could you elaborate?

Moreover, I'd say that it's going to be great if you detail the task you're suppose to implement, instead of questionable architectural decisions already made.

Comment: Sounds like 1+5 should be a different jmx

Comment: TG a runs only once, then you want TG e run after that. So why not putting all requests of TG a and e in on TG to run after each other?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter threads (virtual users) cannot go outside the Thread Group, once started, a thread executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)). When a thread doesn't have more Samplers to execute or loops to iterate - it's being shut down.

Threads are not going to the next Thread Group.

If you need to "pass" a thread from one thread group to another the only way of doing this is starting a brand new thread in another Thread Group and pass the "context" of the thread from the first Thread Group to the new thread, it may include:

- [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- etc.

There are 2 approaches of passing the data between threads in different thread groups:

- Convert the data you want to pass into JMeter Properties using [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function in the first Thread Group so set the value(s) and [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function in the second Thread Group to read the value(s)
- Using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

There was a simple way to do this. Add a throughput controller in the same setUp group b. Make total throughput executions = 1. Done.